# how can i load svg image with get_template_directory_uri() or bloginfo('template_url')

Tags: bloginfo

```
<img alt="Capital" data-inject-svg src="<?php bloginfo( 'template_url' ); ?>/assets/img/logos/imglogo.svg">
```

```
<img alt="Capital" data-inject-svg src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/img/logos/imglogo.svg">
```

i tried both of above code but don't get output

Comment: The image doesn’t appear, or the URL is missing?

Answer (score 0):

remove "data-inject-svg" or use data="data-inject-svg" ...work great ...hire a screenshots

[image: Result img]

[image: Code img]

Answer (score -1):

the answer ;) is :

```
<img alt="Capital" data-inject-svg src="<?php bloginfo( 'template_url' )."/assets/img/logos/imglogo.svg"; ?>">
```

Comment: This is basically exactly the same as the code in the question that isn't working.

Comment: look again... its work fine...

Answer (score -1):

I hope it will your help

Firstly you need to create folder inside the activate theme like this: assets > img > logos > imglogo.svg

If you are working on the child theme can use this:

```
<img alt="Capital" data-inject-svg src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/img/logos/imglogo.svg">
```

Otherwise you can use this:

```
<img alt="Capital" data-inject-svg src="<?php echo bloginfo( 'template_url' ); ?>/assets/img/logos/imglogo.svg">
```